# How to get Bing 'daily mobile wallpaper' address

Tags: iphone

is There anyone know how to get the Bing 'daily mobile wallpaper' address.
if you visit bing.com via your IPhone, you will see a beautiful wallpaper.
Bing change it everyday, and provide two resolution format for Portrait and landscape.

for example, today's Bing mobile wallpaper are from
http://www.bing.com/fd/hpk2/LouetLighthouse_EN-US2132342110_360x480.jpg
http://www.bing.com/fd/hpk2/LouetLighthouse_EN-US2132342110_480x360.jpg

appreciate your help in advance.

Eric

Comment: This answer provides the information you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18096210/202504

Answer (score 6):

parse this url http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=0&n=10

as xml.

you can change value of N to change number of images.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the URL for the wallpaper changes everyday. The only way to would be to scrape the HTML of the page and find where it references the image.

Another similar method would be to use www.istartedsomething . com / bingimages, a site which archives the Bing images. They provide a RSS feed via feedburner for more easy scraping: http://feeds.feedburner.com/bingimages