# Get bing image of the day with Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to fetch image from Bing.com with jquery ajax to set my website background .

I see a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18096210) and try with **JSON** format with bellow code.

```
<head>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {
  var bingImagesUrl = "http://bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx";
  $.getJSON( bingImagesUrl, {
    idx:0,
    n:1,
    format: "js"
  }).done(function( data ) {
  console.log(data)

  });

})();
```

In browser network tab its shows the response
[image]

But ,in console I got error .
[image]

Please tell me what is going wrong a and how to fix.

Comment: You're hitting the CORS restrictions that browsers and servers enforce.  Bing apparently does not allow ajax requests from off site clients to fetch their resources directly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,but I have an question in my mind,can you please help me with that ?I see a link in codeproject https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1119706/Get-Bing-Image-of-the-Day-using-Csharp.My question is then why its working with c# asp.net?